# How to play video from tests saved in cypress container?

Tags: docker, cypress

How do I play video from tests saved within cypress container ? One of my tests is failing when running tests using containerized cypress but isn't failing when running in the terminal. I need to see why is it failing within container but the video is saved in the container.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM cypress/included:7.0.0
WORKDIR /e2e
RUN mkdir /e2e/cypress
ADD integration /e2e/cypress/integration
COPY cypress.json /e2e/cypress.json
RUN npm i randomstring@1.2.2
```

cypress.json:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://nginx",
  "video": true
}
```

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a test run just copy over the saved video from the container to your host machine:

```
docker cp container_name:/e2e/cypress/path/to/video/file /path/to/your/local/folder
```

Replace container_name and update the path to video file (will be the same as running through terminal) and save it somewhere on your local maschine.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/